# How to pass parameter through header?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am developing a system in laravel with vue and in all requests I need to send the client id to do a validation in api. I am using the axios library to make requests to the server.

My first question is how can I send the frontend id through the request header? If this is safe and good practice?

I know it is possible to send with a conventional method. Example: GET parameter or POST parameter.

But I would like to send through the header, because I can create an action in vuex and inject this variable in an abstract way. Without worrying about it with each request.

I thought about doing the following:

**VUEX - STORE.JS**

```
getters: {   
        getHeader: state => {

            let header = {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
               'cliente-id': sessionStorage.getItem("cliente")
            }
            return header;
        },
}
```

and in laravel create a MIDDLEWARE to perform the validation.

It is possible? and is it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to validate user in some way to authenticate, or check if the user of current request is valid, you can use JWT

Here some additional info that can help.

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

https://medium.com/employbl/build-authentication-into-your-laravel-api-with-json-web-tokens-jwt-cd223ace8d1a

https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-authentication-in-vue-using-vuex

About your question if it is possible? Short answer: YES! This is the right way.

It is safe? It depends on your application (what can I do with an user id?), network (are you using ssl/tls?) and other security stuffs. To start, never send critical information in clear text or without encryption.